# how to determine the minimal value in a column of a list of tuples in python

Tags: python

I have the following list of tuples

```
lstoflsts = [(1.2, 2.1, 3.1),
             (0.9, 3.4, 7.4),
             (2.3, 1.1, 5.1)]
```

I would like to get the minimum value of the 2nd column (which is *1.1* based on above example).

I tried playing around with `min(listoflists)` without success.

any suggestions how to approach?
note: if possible I would like to avoid looping over rows and columns...

Comment: `min(zip(*lstoflsts)[1])`?

Comment: @muddyfish: very elegant. please add it as an answer.

Comment: More precisely, you have a list of tuples. If you use a `numpy array` instead, you can just do `min(lstoflsts[:,1])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the love of generator expressions:

```
min(x[1] for x in lstoflsts)
```

Answer (score 11):

Simplest way, you can use `min`,

```
>>> lstoflsts = [(1.2, 2.1, 3.1),
...              (0.9, 3.4, 7.4),
...              (2.3, 1.1, 5.1)]
>>> 
>>> min(lstoflsts, key=lambda x: x[1])
(2.3, 1.1, 5.1)
>>> min(lstoflsts, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
1.1
```

Answer (score 5):

As requested by @udo,

```
min(zip(*lstoflsts)[1])
```

This will change the list so the columns are rows (rotate it) and then get the 2nd (0 based indexing) row (previously column).

Finally, it returns the minimun value.

Comment: and in python 3 it would be `min(list(zip(*lstoflsts))[1])`

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the same way you'd sort a list according to that criterion. Pass a `key` function:

> **min**(*iterable*[, *key*]):
>
> [...] The optional *key* argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for `list.sort()`.

For example using `operator.itemgetter()`:

```
import operator
lstoflsts = [(1.2, 2.1, 3.1),
             (0.9, 3.4, 7.4),
             (2.3, 1.1, 5.1)]
print min(lstoflsts, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
# prints (2.3, 1.1, 5.1)
```

You can also use a lambda expression as key function, of course. However, using `operator.itemgetter()` is generally considered more efficient than the lambda function. It is especially more efficient than anything involving `zip()`.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Answer (score 1):

While sharing a love of generator expressions (which in this case is both one line and beautifully self-documenting once you know Python), is there anything actually wrong with

```
m =lstoflsts[0][1]
for x in lstoflsts: m = min(m, x[1] )
```