# Process CSV files in Python - Zero Imports/No Libraries

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV example like this

```
ID,TASK1,TASK2,QUIZ1,QUIZ2
11061,50,75,50,78
11062,70,80,60,50
11063,60,75,77,79
11064,52,85,50,80
11065,70,85,50,80
```

how do i get the Max, Min and Avg on specific Column?
i want the output like this, if i want to get Avg on `TASK1`

output:

```
Average of TASK1 is 60.4
```

or

```
ID,TASK1,TASK2,QUIZ1,QUIZ2
11061,50,75,50,78
11062,70,80,60,50
11063,60,75,77,79
11064,52,85,50,80
11065,70,85,50,80
AVG,60.4, , , ,
```

so Far my Code like this helped by OlvinRoght

```
with open('file.csv',"r") as f:
    next(f)  # skip first line
    rows = []
    for line in f:
        row = []
        for column in line.split(",")[1:]:  # skip first column
            row.append(int(column))  # convert string to int
            rows.append(row)
    max_row = ['Max']  
    min_row = ['Min']
    for column in zip(*rows):
        max_row.append(str(max(list(zip(*rows))[0])))
        min_row.append(str(min(list(zip(*rows))[0])))
    print(','.join(max_row))
    print(','.join(min_row))
```

Comment: Why can't you use any imports? Splitting on `","` might cause issues in certain cases so handrolling your own CSV parser isn't a great idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to determine the minimal value in a column of a list of tuples in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205413/how-to-determine-the-minimal-value-in-a-column-of-a-list-of-tuples-in-python) Sure, this question asks about tuples instead of lists, but the idea is the same. What trouble do you have with your code?

Comment: I should say that code which used in this question came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963912/10824407) answer but modified and now it contains some indentation and logical issues. If you want to patch code from question, better take source from my answer.

Comment: @erip, it was a requirement to not use any modules, you can check his/her [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69961965/10824407) where this code took from.

Comment: @OlvinRoght how do i take the source from your answer sir?

Comment: @FAISHALYUSUFBAQIR, [like this](https://tio.run/##nZLLasMwEEX3/YpB3djFpIRuSiCLrEoXTXelkIYg4nEy1JaEJOfRn09H8pvuarCx5Dt3zh3ZXP1Rq6dnY2@3M/kjaIMqsaKgEmd7dxIpSAekzK5Y3AFfxpLyiVi/iwwUXnwSv6UZODRLkfEuqnwpuA7uoSSFsNfKS1IOvJXEOwcQX0pEM6vPDpaw2cZVoS13yvGSNYWk2Kuu0EqPTZsM5mmDMaCMKv4H0YIMHB3LXpd1pQJGsJg5UxInz0S6mS@2i2DtvslAQdb5VtzXt6YzaXieeRJAG0UamRjnhNaD8zaweM1d/JjGdZX8no4GH6tlnvPszxErfqvkZTeJUJGabsjTYboxDfhDJnkIbUfjbU07EF72EQZN06fXkPqraVsPgWp@urrqlPAIJfZ14YhjyDnkdCAPsvAYUCs5/v/eVp98yoLvh5azP/xYbbHSJwSsjL@GKQMVoLTnsWGO@cTpdd07NWkGp7Fu9fHS6dpEg@52@wU).

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve achieve this my maintaining aggregated metrics as a list.

```
skip_columns = ["ID"]
num_lines = 0

min_stat = [None]
max_stat = [None]
sum_stat = [0]

with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if num_lines == 0:
            columns = [col.strip() for col in line.split(",")]
            number_of_colums = len(columns)
            min_stat = min_stat * number_of_colums
            max_stat = max_stat * number_of_colums
            sum_stat = sum_stat * number_of_colums
        else:                
            values = [int(col_value.strip()) for col_value in line.split(",")]
            for idx, v in enumerate(values):
                min_stat[idx] = min(v if min_stat[idx] is None else min_stat[idx], v)
                max_stat[idx] = max(v if max_stat[idx] is None else max_stat[idx], v)
                sum_stat[idx] += v
        num_lines += 1
for idx, col in enumerate(columns):
    if col in skip_columns:
        continue
    stat = stats[col]
    print(f"Minimum of {col} is {min_stat[idx]}.")
    print(f"Maximum of {col} is {max_stat[idx]}.")
    print(f"Average of {col} is {sum_stat[idx] / (num_lines - 1)}.")
```

Comment: what if use by list? not dict?
because my team has to use list

Comment: @FAISHALYUSUFBAQIR I have updated the solution to only use lists.